# ambiguous use of subscript swift 2.2

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2, xcode7, xcode7.3

I have a lot of issues in my code with this error. Hopefully if someone can help me here than I can figure out the rest of the problems. I have updated to xcode 7.3 and running swift 2.2.

I have read that the compiler has been "more restrictive", and I have to tell it what the "intermediary" objects are. This is causing me some confusion and would love further explanation.

```
func getMessage(dictionary:NSDictionary)->String{

    var message = String()
    if let dict = dictionary["aps"] {
        if let message:String = dict["alert"] as? String {
            return message
        }
        else{
           message = ""
        }

    }
    return message   
}
```

[image]

Another example:

```
  for object in objects {
            let getDriver = object.objectForKey("driver")

            if let picture = getDriver!["thumbnailImage"] as? PFFile {
                self.profilePictures.append(picture)
            }
            self.requestsArray.append(object.objectId as String!)
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of a dictionary value is always `AnyObject`. Cast the type to something more specific for example

```
if let dict = dictionary["aps"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
```

then the compiler knows that key subscripting is valid and possible

The second example is similar: `object` is a dictionary and the compiler needs to know that the value for key `driver` is also a dictionary

```
if let getDriver = object.objectForKey("driver") as? [String:AnyObject] {
   if let picture = getDriver["thumbnailImage"] as? PFFile {
   ...
```

Comment: Okay thanks, this seems to fix the error for that line of code, so for the second code block in my question what would it be?

Comment: okay because i am using objectForKey, the key itself is just a string so I need to cast it as such? is that sorta correct understanding ?

Comment: `object.objectForKey("driver")` and `object["driver"]` are synonyms. You have to cast the returned **value** from `AnyObject` to a type which can be key subscripted

Comment: Okay so `AnyObject` can't be subscripted, I need to cast dictionary keys to Strings?

Comment: `as [String:AnyObject]` casts the keys to `String` and the values to `AnyObject`.

Comment: oh okay wow makes more sense thanks, 
I will up vote ur answer and accept it now. 

can u look at this question if u have a chance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258298/command-failed-due-to-signal-fault-swift-2-2-xcode-7-3