# Command Failed Due To Signal Fault - Swift 2.2 Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, xcode7.3

I am in the process of updating all my swift syntax after updating to xcode 7.3 
In the process, I got some errors about `ambiguous use of subscript swift` and I believe that this error is also causing the Signal Fault.

[image]

[image]

The code in question:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var arry:NSArray = Array(self.participants)
         arry = arry.sort {
         item1, item2 in
         // ambiguous use of subscript swift error for both these lines
         let date1 = item1["fullName"] as String
         let date2 = item2["fullName"] as String
         return date1 > date2
    }
```

**Edit**

Declaration of `participants` comes from another controller here:

[image]

```
        func gotoMembers(){

        let set:NSSet = self.conversation.participants
        let arr = set.allObjects //Swift Array
        UserManager.sharedManager.queryForAllUsersWithCompletion(arr as! [String], completion:{ (users: NSArray?, error: NSError?) in
            if error == nil {
               //participants declared here and passed into the participant controller
                let participants = NSSet(array: users as! [PFUser]) as Set<NSObject>
                let controller = ParticipantTableViewController(participants: participants, sortType: ATLParticipantPickerSortType.FirstName)
                controller.delegate = self
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated:true);
            } else {
                appDelegate.log.error("Error querying for All Users: \(error)")
            }
        })

    }
```

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Please show the declaration of `self.participants`

Comment: @vadian edited my question

Comment: `let participants` is a local variable and can't be the same as the instance variable (self).`participants`. Is the type of `participants` a set of `PFUser` objects?

Comment: Yeah so it should be a set of PFUsers, this code is basically returning all PFUsers in a certain message. 

Before the update this code was functional, i don't know if something changed after the update, since i haven't had to change this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use Swift native types a much as possible, for example the type of the contents of an `NSArray` object is unspecified.

Second of all use type annotations as few as possible, in the case

```
var array = Array(self.participants)
```

without an annotation you get a Swift `Array` for free and the compiler knows the type of the contents which is `PFUser`. The function `sortInPlace()` sorts the array itself without a return value and you have to forced downcast the `fullName` values to `String`

```
     array.sortInPlace {
        user1, user2 in

        let date1 = user1["fullName"] as! String
        let date2 = user2["fullName"] as! String
        return date1 > date2
}
```

and use the proper type `Set<PFUser>` rather then `Set<NSObject>` and probably `users: [PFUser]?` in the completion handler rather then `users: NSArray?`

Edit: The beginning of the `queryForAllUsersWithCompletion` method is supposed to look like

```
UserManager.sharedManager.queryForAllUsersWithCompletion(arr as! [String], completion:{ (users: [PFUser]?, error: NSError?) in
    if error == nil {
       //participants declared here and passed into the participant controller
       let participants = Set<PFUser>(array: users!)
```

Comment: updating question with ur changes.

Comment: updated my question `type nsobject has no subscript members`

Comment: `arrTmp[indexPath.section]` @kareem

Comment: You're using to many useless annotations and confusing Foundation types which overcharges the compiler.

Comment: `queryForAllUsersWithCompletion` forces me to us use NSArray 

Can u help me with the updated question? I attached an image, has to do with the subscript stuff

Comment: I'm not familiar with Parse, but the cause of the error in the image is the wrongly use of `NSObject` rather than the real type `PFUser`

Comment: so do i have to cast user1, user2 to PFUser?

Comment: Basically yes, but the actual origin is the cast `as Set<NSObject>`, see my edited answer.

Comment: `let item1 = user1 as! PFUser
            let item2 = user2 as! PFUser
            let date1 = item1["fullName"] as! String
            let date2 = item2["fullName"] as! String
            return date1 > date2`

Comment: i casted user1 and user2 then on separate lines and then used them with the subscript